# ask and compare numeric in visual basic or vba

Tags: vba

I have source

```vb
dim test 
test = Format(Val(&h42) And &HF, "00")
```

Why the result is not `test = 02` and how to calculate?

```vb
Val(&h42) = 66
&HF = 15
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `Why the result is not test = 02` - the result *is* `test = 02`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to get `15 + 66 = 81` as result you should have done this:

```
Test = Format(Val(&H42) + Val(&HF), "00")
```

Operator `And` Performs a logical conjunction on Boolean two expressions or a bitwise conjunction on two numeric expressions.

Operator `+` Add two numbers or return the positive value of a numeric expression. Can also be used to concatenate two string expressions.

Also **note** that `Format(Val(&H42) And &HF, "00")` returns `02`